# transitionFromViewController inserts new view in wrong place

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

By wrong I mean not where I expect it. I expect the new view to be in the same back-to-front level as the one it is replacing. In my case, that is *behind* my custom tab bar. Instead the new view comes out in front, obscuring the tab bar.

Is there a way to get the insertion to happen correctly, using this call? Or will I have to handle the view-shuffling, detaching and reattaching of child ViewControllers manually?

Of course I can reorder the views after the transition, but that means the tab bar vanishes and reappears. Grr!

Comment: Hi can you please add screenshot of how you are getting the result and image for how you require your view to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the parent controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews method, and in that method move the tab bar to the front. OR... you can do the same thing in the animation block of the transition method.